# Processing unicode keyboard input within a multi-byte Character set (ansi) mfc windows application

Tags: windows, unicode, mfc

Im my situation i have a huge windows ansi msvc mfc c++ application which cannot be moved to unicode. But still i need to process unicode data at some places. When i create a edit with CreateWindowW, i'm able to copy&paste unicode strings and process it.

But, i fail to get direct keyboard input working.

In a small test app, i logged what is going on when processing keystrokes and when i set it to unicode, WM_KEYDOWN produces a WM_CHAR with a two byte character code:

WM_KEYDOWN  wParam: 00000041 lParam: 001e0001

WM_CHAR     wParam: 000010d0 lParam: 001e0001

but with multi-byte settings. it always producing '?': (while copy&paste is still working)

WM_KEYDOWN  wParam: 00000041 lParam: 001e0001

WM_CHAR     wParam: 0000003f lParam: 001e0001

I believe TranslateMessage is doing this. I somewhat hoped it would take into account if the window is unicode or not and do stuff accordingly, but it seems not.

Summary: I have everything working with unicode (edit, tree, combobox,...). I get unicode into the control using copy&paste. But i fail to get unicode into the controls with direct keyboard input.

So my question would be if there is any way to tap into TranslateMessage and process keystrokes at a unicode window as unicode? Or any other approach to solve that issue?

Any help would very welcome.

Ronald.

Comment: How do you enter that U+10d0 code? It's Georgian character "AN". Do you have Georgian installed on your computer as an input method? It may be garbled even before it reaches your application. It is affected even by the current input method (keyboard language) for the application. Try German ä (ALT+0228).

Comment: Yes, it's an georgian letter. I change the language for the app to georgian and than use the virtual keyboard. I tried ALT+0174 which produce the ®.

Comment: Keyboard input is affected by the current language. On my computer if I enter Alt+0228 with English as current language I get ä (228 is the character code of ä in Windows-1252), while with Greek I get δ (Windows-1253). If I enter Alt+228 I get õ, which is obviously from CP-850! So I have to enter Alt+0xxx, where xxx is the character code in the ANSI-Codepage of the current language! Don't know about Georgian, which seems to not have an ANSI codepage, only Unicode. I cannot enter Georgian from the keyboard in my installation.

Comment: As for your app, I think your goal must be make your Unicode edit-box (in the multibyte app) behave just like Notepad (it's a Unicode edit-box as well). If it doesn't, there's something wrong, so please provide more info, like how and where it is created, eg as a child of a dialog, on a view window, on the toolbar etc, and better post the code that creates it.

Comment: Yes, georgia has no ansi codepage, otherwise i wouldn't need unicode here.

Comment: I just set up a empty desktop app and in InitInstance i do CreateWindowW(L"EDIT", L"",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_VSCROLL|ES_LEFT|ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL,rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom, hWnd, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr); But i think it's not about how it's created, i believe the issue here is, that its part of the ansi app message queue, which at TranslateMessage don't care if its unicode or not. And as msg is routed through the parent windows, which might want to process it, it's even understandable.

Comment: Still, does it work just like Notepad (or a regular Unicode edit-box in a Unicode app)? If not, this means that there's something wrong with your application. Maybe upload your test-application. If yes (but the result is not acceptable), you must invent another way to do it.

Comment: i did upload my simple demo app. https://easyupload.io/ptiuei  (pwd: unicode) it will expire in 7 days. in project settings you can switch between multi-byte and unicode.  The edit looks same for me with both settings.